# Logging working on all environments but one - log4net

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, log4net, global-asax

On a development environment, my web application is properly logging all messages. On the stage environment, the session_end event in global.asax is logged but nothing outside of global.asax gets logged. On dev I can see a basic log when I launch the application showing me logging on, but nothing in stage.

```
-code is same in both environments

-.NET 4.0 web application deployed to IIS

-log4net.config is same in both environments

-logs to text file on same drive as application that runs it

-logger is instantiated in static class, used through whole application.

-global.asax application_start configures logger by building FileInfo object that points to log4net.config and doing this log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.ConfigureAndWatch(file);
```

Does anyone have any advice? I'm sorry if this question is vague or needs more information. I'm unsure where to begin with troubleshooting this. I'll add any requested information.

Comment: Where is it logging to, file, console, database etc.?

Comment: It logs to a text file on the same drive where the application is hosted. Thanks for asking, will add to question

Comment: Is the application running under the context of a user via impersonation or an application pool context? If it's an app pool is it a custom one i.e. not the default? Just thinking if it's impersonation the global.asax code will run in a different security context than the processing of the web request.

Comment: It's an app pool hosted under iis, uses .NET framework 4.0. Configuration of the app pool isn't something I know much about I'm afraid. A separate team in my company handles that piece.

Comment: you mention you are using a `FileInfo` object. can you add a `if (!fileInfo.Exists) throw new Exception("logfile not found at " + fileInfo.FullName)`  so you can rule out a missing file or looking in the 'wrong' location

Comment: Tried that, no luck I'm afraid

Answer (score 0):

The user from your application pool needs to have write rights to the logging directory, check is the rights on both environments are the same.